# installing control panel on vps query

Tags: ubuntu, lighttpd

Bit of a rookie question here(possibly stupid), something I'm just not fully sure off.

I have recently acquired my first VPS(ubuntu) and am looking to install a control panel(webmin).

I'm just wondering, I already have lighttpd web server and mysql installed, so when I install webmin will it work OK along side these, or should I have installed webmin first(if so should I remove current mysql/lighttpd before installing webmin?), or is it not even an issue?

Just looking to understand it fully in my head really.

Many thanks for advice/help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Webmin is only a web-based for Sysadmin. It runs on built-in webserver called miniserv.pl. I'm sure you can install it with existing lighttpd and MySQL.